# Spring Data Neo4j 7.1.1 - relations only return empty sets

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring 3.1.1 with SDN 7.1.1

I have the "Book" class below as a node. The other classes (for example the "Author" class), are also declared as nodes and have the complementing relationship declarations. There are no properties on the relationships.

```
@Relationship(type = "writtenBy", direction = INCOMING)     `
private Set<Book> writtenBy = Collections.emptySet();
```

However, when I use a query to return a Book Node, and using the Getter (for example on "GetAuthors"), only an empty set is returned. I'm using Lombok and the Getters and Setters seem to be included correctly.

When I check the database with a browser, the relationship is there.
Please also see an example from my "BookRepository" interface below:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Book, String> {

   Optional<Book> findOneByTitle(String title);

    boolean existsByTitle(String title);

    @Query("MATCH (book:Book) WHERE book.title = $title RETURN book")
    Book findABookManual(@Param("title") String title);
```

The "findOneByTitle" method is not working properly (it seems to go into a loop there and I don't know why). When I use the Manual Query above, the right node is returned pretty fast, however, the sets of the relationships are always empty sets, even when there are relationships in the database. I read that Lombok might not include "toString" methods automatically for fields not in the constructor, so I did the "ToString.Include", however, it does not work, no matter if it's there or not.

```
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Id;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Node;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Property;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship;

import java.util.*;

import static org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship.Direction.INCOMING;
import static org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Node("Book")

public class Book {

    @Id
    private String title;
    @Property("characters")
    private List<String>characters;
    @Property("genres")
    private List<String> genres;
    @Property("description")
    private String description;
    @Property("bookFormat")
    private String bookFormat;
    @Property("loan")
    private boolean loan;

    @ToString.Include
    @Relationship(type = "published", direction = INCOMING)
    private Set<Publisher> publishers = Collections.emptySet();

    @ToString.Include
    @Relationship(type = "hasFormat", direction = OUTGOING)
    private Set<BookFormat> bookFormats = Collections.emptySet();

    @ToString.Include
    @Relationship(type = "writtenBy", direction = OUTGOING)
    private Set<Author> authors = Collections.emptySet();

    @ToString.Include
    @Relationship(type = "publishedIn", direction = OUTGOING)
    private Set<PublishDate> publishDates = Collections.emptySet();

    @ToString.Include
    @Relationship(type = "hasBorrowed", direction = INCOMING)
    private Set<LibraryUser> Borrowers = Collections.emptySet();



    public Book (String title, List<String> characters, List<String> genres, String description, String bookFormat, boolean loan) {
        this.title = title;
        this.characters = characters;
        this.genres = genres;
        this.description = description;
        this.bookFormat = bookFormat;
        this.loan = loan;

    }
```

Tried the built-in method from Spring Data neo4j to retrieve a node as well as a custom query.

The built in method does not work at all and results in a loop (I think that might be due to a traversal of too many nodes)

Tried the reactive and the "normal" Spring neo4j repository - both with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are setting the set to empty with the Collections.emptySet(), which is causing the issue. Because you aren't then filling that empty set with anything (using an explicit .add method or something similar). I think you want to (instead) initialize a new set and let your results get mapped into it. Hope that makes sense.

This is what I think you need:

```
@Relationship(type = "writtenBy", direction = INCOMING)     `
private Set<Book> writtenBy = new ArrayList<>();
```

If there are further issues, I'm happy to take a look at the code and data model further!